# OpenEdge 10.1C returns datetimetz as a non standard String in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, openedge

I'm trying to access a DB field which represents a `datetimetz` ABL type. I tried `ResultSet.getTimestamp(int)` which should be correct , though the driver complains with `[DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver]Value can not be converted to requested type.`.

I've tried all date and time getters on `ResultSet` which none work. A call to `ResultSet.getObject(int)` returns a `String` representing the value, however this value is a non-standard format which actually has a quirk making it difficult to parse with a `SimpleDateFormat`, this format comes out looking like "`2013-03-08 21:55:10:903 + 11:00`".

From this quirky date it can't be parsed cleanly with a format string due to the space after the `+/-` in the time-zone qualifier and I've had to resort to the following ugly method:

```
String r = rs.getString(col);
if (r == null) {
    return null;
}
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSSXXX",
                                     Locale.getDefault());
try {
    return df.parse(r.substring(0, 23)
                  + r.substring(24, 25)
                  + r.substring(26));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    return null;
}
```

I am using OpenEdge 10.1.C04

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, retrieving TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE values as a time stamp is not supported

Comment: Well, it can. But you have to parse the string yourself :)